# what are differences between Hue and ambari views? which one is better

Tags: hue, ambari

we got a requirement to  install webUI ambari views on HDP cluster which is similar to Hue. Now for the end customer which one would be better and what are the major differences and advantages.

Answer (score 2):

Hue was developed by Cloudera and Ambari View is from developed by HortonWorks. 
Ambari views has capacity scheduler view / slider and Tez view that is not there in Hue, whereas Hue has views for many components.

Answer (score 2):

Ambari is a provisioning tool and once you install Ambari you can create(install) manage the entire cluster. You can keep on expanding by adding nodes and monitor the health, space utilization etc through Ambari.

Ambari views are more to help users to use the installed components/services like hive, pig, capacity scheduler to see the cluster-load and manage YARN  workload management, provisioning cluster resources, manage files etc.

Hue is more flexible compared to ambari-views, and what I think is its user perspective, some users like to use Ambariviews and for others its Hue. Both are good and we are installed both as some users require and used to Hue UI than AmbariViews.

So which one to select? I can say according to the user base. Keep both ready and serve as per user requirements.

Comment: Is it possible to use Hue with HDP and Ambari with Cloudera? If yes, how?